# Chrome Extension port.onDisconnect listener for native connection is not getting called when the native app shuts down

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension code I am establishing a native connection to a native app and now whenever that native app shuts down, the chrome extensions `port.onDisconnect` listener is not getting fired.

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this.

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("host.name");

port.onMessage.addListener(function(data) {});

// Not getting fired when native app shuts down
port.onDisconnect.addListener(function(event) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup the native application host as described in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging)?

Apart from that, you can try to force the port to disconnect by invoking *port.disconnect()*.
Maybe the port doesn't necessarily disconnect when the native application shuts down.

Comment: Yes I have setup the native application as described in the documentation.My requirement is to show a popup on the browser window(my web site) when the native application shuts down.In the popup I need to ask the user to ***"Start the native application if you want to use this site"***